# Where can I access or purchase Aristotelis Opera (edited by Immanuel Bekker)?

Tags: aristotle, ancient-philosophy, greeks

I have been trying to find the following as I am very interested in reading Aristotle in the original Greek:

Aristotle. Aristotelis opera. Edited by Immanuel Bekker, Christian August Brandis, and Hermann Bonitz. 4 vols. Academia Regia Borussica [The Royal Prussian Academy]. Berlin: Georg Reimer, 1831.

Can it be found by any classical studies publisher?

Thanks

Comment: https://archive.org/details/aristotelisopera05arisrich It was published nearly 200 years ago, so there's no copyright infringement that I'm aware of. It's free to read online.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel Greek-English Aristotle followed by [St. Thomas Aquinas](https://isidore.co/aquinas/)'s commentary in parallel Latin-English or just English:

> **Commentaries on Aristotle**
>
> Peri Hermeneias ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/PeriHermeneias.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/PeriHermeneias.htm))
>
> Posteriora Analytica ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/PostAnalytica.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/PostAnalytica.htm))
>
> Physica ([Latin & English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Physics.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/Physics.htm))
>
> De cœlo et mundo ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeCoelo.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/DeCoelo.htm))
>
> De generatione et corruptione
>   [PDF](https://isidore.co/aquinas/GenCorrup.pdf) ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/GenCorrup.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/GenCorrup.htm))
>
> Super Meteora [PDF](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Meteora.pdf)
>   ([Latin & English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Meteora.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/Meteora.htm))
>
> De anima ([Latin & English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeAnima.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/DeAnima.htm))
>
> De sensu et sensato ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/SensuSensato.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/SensuSensato.htm))
>
> De memoria et reminiscentia ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/MemoriaReminiscentia.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/MemoriaReminiscentia.htm))
>
> Ethica ([Latin & English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/Ethics.htm))
>
> Tabula Ethicorum
>   ([Latin](https://isidore.co/aquinas/http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/cte01.html))
>
> Politica ([Latin & English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Politics.htm))
>
> Metaphysica ([Latin &
>   English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Metaphysics.htm) /
>   [English](https://isidore.co/aquinas/english/Metaphysics.htm))

[Perseus has some of Aristotle's works in Greek](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/collection?collection=Perseus:collection:Greco-Roman#Aristotle,0,18), too.